# Calculated measure which returns average number of site key per day

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a calculated measure which  returns average number of site keys per day.

Fact table looks like below.

[image]

Formula for measure is sum of number of distinct keys of each day divided by number of days for that month..

Calculated Measure = SUM(Distinct Keys of Day1, Distinct Keys of Day2,....Distinct Keys of last day of month)/ Number of days of month.

Any suggestion is appreciated and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you supply the mdx you have tried so far please

Comment: @whytheq, here is mdx so far


WITH Member [Measures].[DistinctKeys]
AS DISTINCTCOUNT(SIteKeys),

WITH Member [Measures].[AvgKeysPerDay]
AS AVG([DimDate].[Hierarchy].[Day].Members,[Measures].[DistinctKeys])

SELECT [Measures].[AvgKeysPerDay] ON Columns,
[DimDate].[Month Name].[Month Name].Members ON Rows
FROM Violations

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view your calculated member will be something like:

```
SET [Used Keys] AS 
  NONEMPTY([Key].[Key].[Key], [Measures].[Count])
MEMBER [AVG Keys] AS 
  AVG(
    [Date].[Month].&[2017-01].Children, 
    DistinctCount([Used Keys])
)
```